# apostrophe php issue

Tags: php, apostrophe

I was making a school assignment with involves a shoutbox. A found great tutorial wich uses jquery,ajax,mysql and php. Now i run into a little problem with the following sentence:

```
$result .= "<li><strong>".$row['user']."</strong><img src="\" alt="\"-\""    />".$row['message']." <span class="\"date\"">".$row['date']."</span></li>";}
```

I was wondering if anybody could find out why it gives errors. So far I came to this conclusion `$row['message']` and then it thinks the rest of the code as a string. So it probably is a apostrophe problem.

Comment: Look at the way StackOverflow editor has highlighted your code. See where the contents colour between the `"`'s that you want to actually show as `$result` has changed. This should help you figure out why your code is throwing errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the sake of making your life easier: use `'` for the php and `"` for html like this:

```
$result .= '<li><strong>'.$row['user'].'</strong><img src="" alt=""/>'.$row['message'].' <span class="date">'.$row['date'].'</span></li>';
```

Pretty sure you should get the idea.

Comment: This one is IMHO the most clear solution. If row is not filtered yet (what I guess by the name), then you will probably like to sanitize your output using `htmlspecialchars()` in order to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Yeah absolutely agree, but I am pretty sure the context of the question itself was not at the level of attack prevention nor it was asking about it. However, a good tip for the future for the asker :)

Comment: I'm going to look into htmlspecialchars(). Thanks for the tip. This seems to be the solution wich i will accept in about 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$result .= "<li><strong>{$row['user']}</strong><img src='http://www.' alt='My Alt Tag' />{$row['message']}<span class='date'>{$row['date']}</span></li>";
```

You're confusing yourself by coming in and out of quotations - you can wrap variables with {} to force the interpolation in such cases.

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue. Their are some other problems but i will try it myself. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result .= "<li><strong>".$row['user']."</strong><img src='' alt='-'/>".$row['message']." <span class='date'>".$row['date']."</span></li>";}
```

Avoid using " inside of the string - it is easy to forget about escaping special chars. Instead of " use '.
Besides - you use " only when there is any PHP parsing necessary within this string. E.g.

```
$var1 = 1;
$test = "$var1"; //evaluates to '1'
$test = '$var1'; //evaluates to '$var1'
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are attempting to escape quotes and making your job harder.  A great feature in PHP for HTML output is using quoted strings so that you don't have to worry about escaping double quotes. Please reference the [PHP Manual for Strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

In other words your line becomes:

```
 $result .= '<li><strong>' . $row['user'] . '</strong><img src="" alt="-" />' . $row['message'] .
            '<span class="date">' . $row['date'] . '</span></li>' .
            '<li><strong>' . $row['user'] . '</strong><img src="" alt="-" />' . $row['message'] . 
            '<span class="date">' . $row['date'] . '</span></li>';
```